# how do I get smooth scrolling when I scroll the website page?

Tags: javascript, gsap

Could anyone please tell me how I get smooth scrolling on the page using gsap or vanilla js.
I"m using gsap to create animation on my page
and using this code but when I'm using this code, my animation just messed up. So I need to know can I do smooth scrolling using gsap

```
enter code  const body = document.body,
            scrollWrap = document.getElementsByClassName("smooth-scroll-wrapper")[0],
            height = scrollWrap.getBoundingClientRect().height - 1,
            speed = 0.04;

        var offset = 0;

        body.style.height = Math.floor(height) + "px";

        function smoothScroll() {
            offset += (window.pageYOffset - offset) * speed;

            var scroll = "translateY(-" + offset + "px) translateZ(0)";
            scrollWrap.style.transform = scroll;

            callScroll = requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
        }

        smoothScroll();here
```

Comment: You don't need JS to implement the actual animation: Why aren't you using a CSS animation for this?

Comment: Is this what you’re looking for: html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }

Comment: no no, you don't understand. have a look at this page https://normandubois.design/projects/kikovi/ . I want that kind of smooth scrolling